# Using Adreno GPU for deep learning

Tags: python, gpu, opencl, pyopencl

I need to use Adreno GPU for deep learning (TensorFlow, PyTorch) instead of Nvidia is there has anyone know how? I'm using Python what do I have to do I really have no idea. I also got the `adreno_opencl_ml_sdk_v3.0` driver but I don't know how to use it.

```
# import pyopencl as cl
import pyopencl.cltypes
import pyopencl.array
import numpy as np

device = torch.device("opencl")

a = torch.tensor(\[1, 2, 3\], dtype=torch.float32).to("opencl")
b = torch.tensor(\[4, 5, 6\], dtype=torch.float32).to("opencl")
c = a + b
print(c)
```

This is the error:

```
RuntimeError: PyTorch is not linked with support for opencl devices
```

Comment: Welcome on stack overflow. Can you please edit the title to give a rough idea what you are asking? "Hi ladies&gents" does not make sense in a title.